# DynamoDB: When does 1MB limit for queries apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) for DynamoDB it says:

> In a Query operation, DynamoDB retrieves the items in sorted order, and then processes the items using `KeyConditionExpression` and any `FilterExpression` that might be present.

And:

> A single Query operation can retrieve a maximum of 1 MB of data. This limit applies before any `FilterExpression` is applied to the results.

Does this mean, that `KeyConditionExpression` is applied before this 1MB limit?

Comment: this means that for a query if the `FilterExpression` alone has an output of 1MB then this limit is applied

Comment: @error404 Are you sure? I understand it X has to be <= 1MB, then X gets filtered to Y and is especially < 1MB.

Comment: @J.Hesters — Your understanding has always been my impression and how I interpret the docs: `KeyConditionExpression` produces at most 1MB of data, and is further filtered to return you less than 1MB.

Comment: @readyornot that's how I understand it, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Indeed, your interpretation is correct. With `KeyConditionExpression`, DynamoDB can  efficiently fetch only the data matching its criteria, and you only pay for this matching data and the 1MB read size applies to the matching data. But with `FilterExpression` the story is different: DynamoDB has no efficient way of filtering out the non-matching items before actually fetching all of it *then* filtering out the items you don't want. So you **pay** for reading the entire unfiltered data (before `FilterExpression`), and the 1MB maximum also corresponds to the unfiltered data.

If you're still unconvinced that this is the way it should be, here's another issue to consider: Imagine that you have 1 gigabyte of data in your database to be Scan'ed (or in a single key to be Query'ed), and after filtering, the result will be just 1 kilobyte. Were you to make this query and expect to get the 1 kilobyte back, Dynamo would need to read and process the entire 1 gigabyte of data before returning. This could take a very long time, and you would have no idea how much, and will likely timeout while waiting for the result. So instead, Dynamo makes sure to return to you after every 1MB of data it reads from disk (and for which you pay ;-)). Control will return to you 1000 (=1 gigabyte / 1 MB) times during the long query, and you won't have a chance to timeout. Whether a 1MB limit actually makes sense here or it should have been more, I don't know, and maybe we should have had a different limit for the response size and the read amount - but definitely some sort of limit was needed on the read amount, even if it doesn't translate to large responses.

By the way, the `Scan` documentation includes a slightly differently-worded version of the explanation of the 1MB limit, maybe you will find it clearer than the version in the `Query` documentation:

> A single Scan operation will read up to the maximum number of items set (if using the Limit parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data and then apply any filtering to the results using FilterExpression.